# Custom Font no display in IOS (.otf type)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, fonts

My below San Fransico font not working 
[Download here and test](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)

I have added all the otf file in the  .plist and use the name to set font in the code using font manager as below

```
lbl_1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIDisplay-Bold" size:20];
lbl_2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIDisplay-Medium" size:20];
lbl_3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Light" size:20];
lbl_4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Regular" size:20];
lbl_5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Semibold" size:20];
```

NOTE: I download the .ttf and its working using Zil answer

Comment: did u add otf file in project?

Comment: I added a rather complete answer, I hope you find what you need in there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are common mistakes to fonts not working, let me list them all and I'm sure you'll find your issue :

- Make sure you've added the fonts in your project, and that you can see them in XCode. You could put them in the root folder or in a specific folder.
- Make sure they've the correct target, or that they actually have a target at all ;) Tick the box and you're good

Look at this image for point 1 & 2.
[image: fonts are in the right folder and have correct target]

- Make sure your image is included as Resources of your current bundle :

[image]

- Make sure you reference them in your .plist file, if they're in a cusotm folder, i'm pretty sure you need to write down the relative path, not only the name.

[image]

- Make sure you're using the correct font name, that you can find using the following code snippets :

Objective-C :

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
{
     print("\(family)")
     for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
     {
         print("== \(names)")
     }
}
```

Don't forget to remove that code after you're done. This will help you make sure you're indeed using the correct family name for the font, which can sometime vary from the actual name you see using the Font viewer of OSX.

Note : if your fonts dont' print, that means they're not in the project, if they print, that means you didn't succeed into loading them, but that they're in the project. This specific step could help you pinpoint the problem.

[image]

- Actually use the font :

  ```
  UIFont myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"QuicksandDash-Regular" size:35];
  ```

Thanks to [Chris](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) for the actual tips

I'm 100% sure the correct answer is somewhere in here, so make sure that everything is correct on your end. Unless you've done something specificly against using fonts, repeating these steps should be enough.
 You could try using an empty project and compare the results, which often helps when encountering "unresolvable problems"

Comment: I would also note that it's worth hunting around for a different version of the font you're trying to install. The font I was trying to present in app did not work. My designer found a different version (different SHA sum) of that font, same file type (otf), same font style, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**
 Make sure you added font in project.

**Step 2 :**
Make sure you added font in `info.plist`

**Step 3 :**
Make sure you added font in `Copy Bundle Resources`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** Make sure you added font file in project.

**Step 2 :** Run below code in AppDelegate and check what font names you are getting.

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"--Font name: %@", fontName);
    }
}
```

May be font name is different then what you are using.